mixing `cout.width` and ios::POSITION
So I am learning streams, and there's an unexpected output when I mix cout.width(20) and cout.setf(ios::left) Take a look at the following code.
    cout.width(20);
    cout.setf(ios::left);
    cout.fill('*');
    cout << 20;

Output:
20******************                  `
If I comment out the second line, the 20 will be on right. If I switch the 1st and 2nd line, it still provides the same output. Doesn't setf and width contradict each other? I know width is indeed in effect due to the astricks, but shouldn't the 20 still be on the right as that's how width works? Also what is meant by "flush left" and "flush right"
Any explanation would be great.

Width and adjustment (the "alignment") are orthogonal to each other. Why do you think they would contradict each other?

Width is how wide a field is. Left and Right is which side the padding is on. No idea what you're asking about flush.

Flush left is aligned to the left with a "ragged" right, like most English books and the text in your question. Flush right is aligned to the right with a "ragged" left margin, as e.g. Arabic text.

An empty 20-character field with * filler looks like
********************

With left alignment, left-to-right text starts at the left edge:
20******************

With right alignment, left-to-right text ends at the right edge:
******************20

The width has no effect on alignment.
